# Meaning of USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ, `<option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />` keeps getting generated in `codeStyleConfig.xml` file situated inside `.idea/codeStyles`.

Just wanted to know its purpose and if should I commit this to my vcs given I have maintained a project specific style under vcs as `<option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="ProjectStyle"` in the same file

1. What role does this tag have?
2. How will it affect the shared style `ProjectStyle.xml` defined inside `.idea/codeStyles`?
3. Should I keep it in my vcs for sharing my code style?

The original content of the `codeStyleConfig.xml` as below

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="ProjectStyle" />
  </state>
</component>
```

But sometimes it gets converted to as below

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="ProjectStyle" />
  </state>
</component>
```

Here, `ProjectStyle` is the name of the style as per my company name so preferably I don't want to change to some other name

Answer (score 0):

The value `<option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />` is set when you select scheme `Stored in Project` in Code Style settings under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Scheme`:

[image]

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.2/settings-code-style.html#scheme :

```
The location where the scheme is stored is written next to each scheme, for example,
the Default scheme is stored in the IDE, 
the Project scheme is stored in the project.
```

So, if you need to define code style settings for a specific project only and share
it with the team you can keep `USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS = true` , remove `PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE` and commit to VCS

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have a few doubts what is the use of `PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE`. From the name it seems that it can be used to specify which project style to choose present in `.idea/codeStyles`

Also, let's say my project style has a custom name `ProjectStyle.xml` will just having `USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS` work?